# src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns1:UmciAttributeType' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

"src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns1:UmciAttributeType' to a(n) 'type definition' component." This error is shown in wsdl file

```
 <complexType name="UmciAttribute">
<complexContent>
 <extension base="tns1:UmciRoot">
  <sequence>
   <element name="domain" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="inherited" type="xsd:boolean"/>
   <element name="keyName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="newName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="parent" nillable="true" type="tns1:UmciElementID"/>
   <element name="type" nillable="true" type="tns1:UmciAttributeType"/>
   <element name="value" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  </sequence>
 </extension>
</complexContent>
```

The error is in this line: `<element name="type" nillable="true" type="tns1:UmciAttributeType"/>`

and on creating a webservice from a java file the following error is shown:
"IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from `WSDL:  java.io.IOException: Type  UmciAttributeType` is referenced but not defined." I think this error is due to the above mentioned error in WSDL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty obvious. It's saying that type `UmciAttributeType` is not defined. It should be defined somewhere in that file.

You also have a `UmciElementID` type and it isn't giving error, so it must be defined somewhere, just like `UmciAttributeType` should be.

Comment: actually I am using 'UmciAttribute' in my method and its defined as well but i dont know from where does this 'UmciAttributeType' comes!? When i remove "Type" from 'UmciAttributeType' then it shows no error! :D